# how can I bypass recaptcha while using python requests?

Tags: http, captcha, bot

How can I bypass the recaptcha on a website with python requests so that I don't have to solve it?

Comment: You can't. That's literally why it exists. You can use a third party service to solve them for you, but that's hardly "bypassing" it.

Comment: It will depend entirely on the options or weaknesses in the site to bypass it. Recaptcha exists to prevent bots from getting past it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked a very interesting question that I am going to give an interesting answer too.

You can not bypass a recaptcha, unless as @schroeder stated, where there is a weakness or an option on the site where you can bypass it.  You might have to do some experimenting to see and find out if this is the case.

A more exact solution involves multiple requests, as well as requests to other websites.  First make a request that causes the recaptcha to appear.  Then take the received info and send a web request via python, to a re-captcha third party solving service, that accepts recaptcha question data from online requests.  Then from the answers you get back from them, send that as requests via python back to where it answers are sent for recaptcha questions.  This way you are solving the recaptchas by sending requests via python.  hYou still are not bypassing, however you are sending requests via python to get thru the recaptcha.

Another solution for python *might* be able to solve the recaptcha, and **send a request** so that the recaptcha is passed.  Basically when you solve a recaptcha, your results are sent via POST request.  Although not exactly a 100% answer to your question, but it does involve sending requests via python.

Solving the recaptcha in using python however would require intense machine learning, precise image recognition, and AI programing knowledge, most of those are probably still not yet at par 100% to successfully do every captcha.  Also, the recaptcha was designed also to be difficult for bots to solve even.